# Windows 8 Command Line Runas sending a password with a bat file

Tags: windows-8, acl, runas

I want to use a .bat file to run a program at the windows 8 command line as 'aaron-desk/administrator'.  This account has no password.

I've tried the runas command, but this give me an error message that blank passwords aren't allowed.  Is there a way to have my .bat file send it a password?

I am running command line from PHP (and WAMP) and am the 'nt authority/system' user.

(I'm trying to get node.exe to run at the command line to do a TileMill / Mapnik export. It works with the regular command line, but not when I open it with PHP probably because my user name is different.)

Comment: I ended up setting most of my environmental variables to be the same as the other user. Turns out it wasn't a permissions issue, it was the environmental variables that mattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot natively pass a password to the `runas` command, however you may consider looking at [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

Either set a password or allow the use of blank passwords as shown here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737553(v=ws.10).aspx